# Disable atime and diratime on USB flash drive with udev

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, removable-storage, fat

I have a USB flash drive which is used for doing backups.  I've noticed that when I do the backups, the access times for files and folders are getting updated.

Is there any way I can disable the atime/diratime options on USB flash drives?  I'm assuming it would require a udev rule, since my USB flash drive is not specified in my /etc/fstab file.

Or would this be a moot point?  I'm not sure if the Linux supports atime and diratime for FAT filesystems.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with the LXDE desktop (so, Lubuntu).

Comment: You can specify `noatime` when mounting. Note that by default, modern Linux systems use `relatime`, which doesn't update the atime most of the times. To specify different settings, you need to pass an option to `mount` when mounting. How are your disks mounted? It seems you're using some automatic mount-on-insert, but which one? If you don't know, what distribution are you using and what desktop environment?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with the LXDE desktop (so, Lubuntu).

Comment: What is diratime? Edit: found it https://wiki.archlinux.de/title/Noatime .